# I delete watson-conversation's Entities by mistake

Tags: watson-conversation

I delete watson-conversation's Entities by mistake.
Where I can find it and restore it,
or I lost it?

Comment: It's gone. Unless you made a backup of the workspace, or exported the entities.

Comment: Maybe the log can help you find the pieces of it then you can gather them back. Have you checked the log?

Comment: I didn't have version controlling. But Only after this mistake i have learnt how important it is to maintain the project in an SVN or Git.Thanks.